# IP address for connecting server on the same LAN using SignalR

Tags: java, android, signalr, ip-address

I'm trying to create a SignalR connection between an ASP.NET server (SignalR-Server 3.0.0) and an Android client on a real device. So far I've managed to successfully establish a connection on the same computer using a console application client targeting the IP `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

The server computer and the Android device are both connected to the same LAN (over Wi-Fi), so I tried to set the target IP to be the server computer LAN IP, but an exception is thrown:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.14.167
>   (port 5000) after 15000ms

Here's the relevant client app, using [SignalR Java client](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client):

```
Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent()); 

String serverUrl = "http://192.168.14.167:5000/signalr";
mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy("Hub");
ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);

try {
    signalRFuture.get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Am I missing anything/doing anything wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pls use web browser (both in PC and phone) to access "http://192.168.14.167:5000/signalr" and post the result

Comment: I first tried `localhost:5000/signalr` on PC as a test case and got a response "(Protocol error: Unknown transport."). When trying the address you suggested (I moved to a different LAN so a different IP, but same same), there's no response both on PC and on the Android device. As a desperate move I tried the network's public IP, but still no response... any idea?

Comment: Hello, Did you solve your issue? : )

Comment: @Rybzor Sorry, I neglected this work since our server is running ASP.NET Core, which SignalR is not compatible with (at the moment).

Comment: was the problem solved ? I have the same issue